# Does usage of customer key id generates additional GAE datastore write operation?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, quota

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Data(ndb.Model):
    data = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
```

Is the number of write operations equal in the following two cases:

```
record = Data()
record.data = data_string
record.put_async()

record = Data(id=data_string) # custom id is used
record.data = data_string
record.put_async()
```

Or, the second case requires more write operations? [Understanding write cost](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Understanding_write_costs) Google article doesn't clarify it.

Comment: Why would you think that the custom id would require more operations?

Comment: @JimmyKane, I just don't know. Automatic ID/Name is Numeric, if I assign it manually - it could be String. Also, I don't know how it works from GAE side - probably, when I assign custom id, still it keeps (and writes) somewhere automatic id.

Comment: have you profiled it via appstats? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, no, I haven't. Does it provide such kind of details? (never used appstats before)

Comment: yes, it profiles put etc.

Comment: Definately profile it, though appstats only profiles your code and it's rpcs not what goes on in the google service layer.  My guess is it won't be different or possibly quicker if you provide the key_name (no extra writes). With a key_name provided the underlying service doesn't have to find/allocate a new unique id for the "app/namespace/path".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store data_string twice in your second example. If you use a string to create an entity key, you can extract it back from the key.

Because you do not index this property, however, the writing costs would be the same, but the data volume will be smaller.

Comment: Could I store the data just as a key? Without having any other property? As far as I remember Google documentation, storing `None` as `data` value will also cost me 1 operation.

Comment: Storing None will cost you 2 operations if the property is indexed. I don't think it costs anything for an unindexed property. BTW, I am using a low-level Java API which allows me not to have a property in a data store entity if the corresponding data object property is null, empty or has a default value. I don't know if there is an equivalent in Python.